Anaconda 3: nbconvert failed: PdfFileWriter is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfWriter instead
ANACONDA 3 - Windows 11
Jupyter Lab: File -> Save As -> PDFviaHTML fails with the error below.
Anaconda Prompt command Line: jupyter nbconvert -to xxx yyy.ipynb fails with the same error
PdfFileWriter is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfWriter instead.
Help please!
Thanks!
I examined a number of web solutions to the problem.  All of the solutions I saw took me into other packages, Camelot was one.  Strongly to desire solve the problem without installing, or installing as few as possible, packages.

Just use the new import - it is backwards-compatible. And while you are at it: PyPDF2 is not maintained anymore in favor of pypdf.

Fixed it!  I used the command "conda install pypdf2" which took me back to the version 2.11.1.  Everything executes as advertised with the previous version.
All good now.
